# Java serial communication: Rxtx unable to find serial ports on FriendlyARM mini2440

Tags: java, linux, arm, rxtx, javax.comm

I am attempting to get the Java rxtx library to work on the FriendlyARM mini2440. I am
using emDebian "squeeze" on the mini244. The rxtx library is taken from
"lenny" as the squeeze version does not match my requirements. The Java
environment works fine and does not complain about not identifying the rxtx
classes. The problem seems to be that it cannot identify any of the serial
ports on the machine. Any comments or suggestions would be greatly
appreciated.